# Jquery attr function vs. is function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When testing whether a specific element is checked or not in html using jquery
What is the difference between 
`$(elem).attr('checked')` and `$(elem).is(':checked')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(elem).attr('checked')` gets the value of the `checked` attribute, whereas `$(elem).is(':checked')` checks to see whether the element is actually checked or not.

Answer (score 2):

`.attr` will check the actual `checked` attribute, although it's worth mentioning that `.attr`  has been replaced with `.prop` for checking such attributes. `.is` checks the state of the element.

All in all, you should use `this.checked` if inside the actual element.

Answer (score 1):

You should try `console.log` these next time but basically one returns the value and the other one returns `true`\ `false`

Answer (score 0):

`attr()` get/sets the element's *attribute*. When a user checks or unchecks a checkbox, the `checked` *property* is changed, not the attribute. `is(':checked')` reads the `checked` property, which could also be done as `.prop('checked')` or `elem.checked`.